# Measuring the distance between data points based on mutual linkages

Tags: similarity, distribution, distance

How to measure the distance between two data points (or: nodes?) based on their mutual share of linkages?

I don't know the technical term for that, so here is **a fictitious example from scientific publishing**:

- Say that 20% of all citations from the journal *Acta Mathematica* go to the journal *Nature*.
- Only 5% of all citations from *Acta Mathematica* go to the *Romanian Journal of Physics*.
- On the other hand, *Nature* never cites *Acta Mathematica*, ...
- ... while 10% of the *Romanian Journal of Physics*' citations go to *Acta Mathematica*.

| citing | cited | share |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acta Mathematica | Nature | 15% |
| Acta Mathematica | Romanian Journal of Physics | 8% |
| Nature | Acta Mathematica | 0% |
| Romanian Journal of Physics | Acta Mathematica | 10% |

Given such inter-linkages, the *Romanian Journal of Physics* and *Acta Mathematica* are "closer" to each other than the *Romanian Journal of Physics* and *Nature*.

Is there a conventional way to calculate such distances?

I believe it would be too simplistic and wrong to just sum the mutual shares? I mean in the form of:

| journal1 | journal2 | sum(share) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acta Mathematica | Romanian Journal of Physics | 18% |
| Acta Mathematica | Nature | 15% |

This seems too un-sophisticated and counterintuitive. If *Acta Mathematica*'s citations to *Nature* would amount to 20%, then *Nature* would be "closer" to *Acta Mathematica* than the *Romanian Journal of Physics* is? This doesn't sound right to me.

I would be grateful for any hints regarding algorithms that would "objectively" measure such distances!

Comment: This is definitely a graph problem. There are certainly many methods for calculating distances in a weighted graph, as well as clustering methods to group nodes together. There might also be a probabilistic angle to it.